# Combination Single-tenant and multi-tenant infrastructure

Tags: database, multi-tenant, saas, infrastructure

I am evaluating the best approach for migrating our current on-premises Java Web app to a SAAS platform.  Application multi-tenancy seems straight-forward, but less so with the database.  We're probably all aware of the database-per-tenant pros at this point: isolation, performance, reduced backup/restore complexity, and much lower retrofit complexity.  Naturally the row-per-tenant approach has its benefits as well, reduced infrastructure costs being a major one.

Is it unheard of to combining the two approaches?  That way the database-per-tenant approach faster time-to-market while the development changes to support a multi-tenant database are being made gradually.  Once both approaches are operational customers with particularly heavy workloads or security constraints could have their own isolated database, but the default would be using a shared common database (for cost/efficiency reasons).  Does anyone have any experience using/seeing this combination of approaches in the real world?

Whether requests are routing to datasource by tenant ID, or the tenant ID is an argument to the SQL queries, the major differences should be contained with in the persistence layer/database somewhat limiting the added complexity of combining the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are complexities when we scale out a tenant, i.e. moving a tenant data from the shared database to that of the isolated database.

The automation of this process requires effort and testing due to the identification of the entity tables, mapping tables and ordering of these steps to process the migration successfully. The strategy used for the database like `ORM` or `ADO.NET` also needs to be considered for this process.

Compared to having a row wise `tenantid`, if we can use a schema per tenant within the same database, it will be easier to perform this kind of migration.

We did try this out initially, but since there was framework data and application / business data, it was little difficult to resolve the migration to happen automatically, given lesser time-frame, however with the right time and plan, this can be achieved.